# why this code showing a dwapi::configure()?

Tags: r

How can I get this code correct?

```
library("data.world")
file_df <- download_file_as_data_frame(
  "jonloyens/an-intro-to-dataworld-dataset",
  "fatal-police-shootings-data.csv")
```

> Error in auth_token() : API authentication must be configured  before any functions can be invoked.  To configure, use dwapi::configure().

Comment: Well, it certainly appears that you need to investigate the data resource that is being accessed. I can only imagine that this is described in the help pages for the package and the DESCRIPTION file that is part of it..

Answer (score 1):

So to illustrate why I wrote that comment:

```
packageDescription('data.world')
Package: data.world
Title: Functions and Add-Ins for Working with 'data.world' Data Sets and Projects
Version: 1.2.2
Authors@R: c( person("Rafael", "Pereira", email = "rafael.pereira@data.world", role =
         c("aut", "cre")), person("Triet", "Le", email = "triet.le@data.world", role =
         c("aut")), person("Bryon", "Jacob", email = "bryon.jacob@data.world", role =
         c("aut")), person("Scott", "Came", email = "scott@cascadia-analytics.com",
         role = c("aut")))
Description: High-level tools for working with 'data.world' data sets. 'data.world' is
         a platform where you can find interesting data, store and showcase your own
         data and data projects, and find and collaborate with other members. In
         addition to exploring, querying and charting data on the data.world site, you
         can access data via 'API' endpoints and integrations. Use this package to
         access, query and explore data sets, and to publish your insights. Visit
         <https://data.world>, for additional information.
Depends: R (>= 3.3.0), dwapi (>= 0.1.3)
Imports: httr, ini, miniUI, shiny, stringi
Suggests: covr, knitr, lintr, readr, rmarkdown, testthat (>= 2.0.0)
License: Apache License 2.0
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
URL: https://github.com/datadotworld/data.world-r
BugReports: https://github.com/datadotworld/data.world-r/issues
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
VignetteBuilder: knitr
NeedsCompilation: no
Packaged: 2018-04-04 20:36:39 UTC; root
Author: Rafael Pereira [aut, cre], Triet Le [aut], Bryon Jacob [aut], Scott Came [aut]
Maintainer: Rafael Pereira <rafael.pereira@data.world>
Repository: CRAN
Date/Publication: 2018-04-04 22:29:14 UTC
Built: R 3.6.1; ; 2019-09-16 05:09:34 UTC; unix
```

Every package accepted by CRAN needs a DESCRIPTION file and that shows how you can access from your console. It's a text file with specific requirements. One of the functions is to point you to other packages that are needed for successful functioning as well as external sources of code or in this case data. You should, therefore, go to the value for the "URL:" line, ie. https://github.com/datadotworld/data.world-r and educate yourself. Other times you may need to install System packages, although this particular package does not list any.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for `dwapi::configure()` can be found in the [Configuration](https://github.com/datadotworld/dwapi-r#configuration) section of that README on Github.

In short, requests to the data.world API require a user token (even a free user token), and the error indicates that a token is not being sent properly.